# Can't connect to MySQL with Spring in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot

I have mysql running in a docker container:

```
docker run -it --name mysql-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=root mysql:latest
docker start mysql-db
```

I want to run my Spring Boot application (with Maven) in another docker container:

```
docker build -t java-app .
docker run -it --name java-app --link mysql-db:mysql -p 8080:8080 java-app
docker start java-app
```

But I get an exception:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused)

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/share/demo/demo.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/usr/share/demo/demo.jar"]
```

My application.yml:

```
spring:
    # General JPA properties
    jpa:
        show-sql: false
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
        # Hibernate Specific properties
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: false
    # DataSource configuration
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db
        username: root
        password: root
```

What is my problem?

MySQL logs have warnings about `-skip-name-resolve mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your database isn't working at all. You can verify this by running `docker ps` or `docker exec -it mysql-db mysql -u root -proot db` in 2nd terminal. It will probably fail. Reason to this is `-e MYSQL_USER=root` flag you use. This docker image creates root user with password you've provided so when you want to create root user again it fails and shuts down container. Just change it to `-e MYSQL_USER=myuser` and it should work.

Comment: Database is working, I checked it with both commands.
And your advice didn't change anything.
But thank you anyway.

Comment: I've reproduced your commands and db failed to fully initialize. You do docker start again but not sure if it brings up working db. When you run my docker exec command can you do queries like: SHOW TABLES; ?

Comment: Yes, I can do queries.

Comment: I forgot to recreate image (with changing in yml), when I tried this flag `-e MYSQL_USER=myuser`.
So I tried it again and now all works.
Thank you very much!

Comment: What about the user declared in your application.yml? Did you keep it as root user and root password? Or we only need to change the value  -e MYSQL_USER=myuser

Comment: Only need to change the value, If I remember correctly.